# How can I fix this list append save function to a file?

Tags: python

I want it to save succesfully

```
outfile = open(file_name, "w")
for i in card_list:
    outfile.append(str(card_list[i]) + "\n")
```

```
try:
    card_list=[]
    for i in range (5):
        card = int(input("Enter a card number: "))
        while card <1 or card > 13:
            print("Invalid Card")
            card = int(input("Enter a card number: "))
        card_list.append(card)
    print(card_list)

    file_name = input("What name would you like to save them as? ")

    outfile = open(file_name, "w")
    for i in card_list:
        outfile.append(str(card_list[i]) + "\n")
    print()
    print("Your cards were successfully saved.")
    print()
except ValueError:
    print()
    print("Card must Be an integer not a string.")
    print()
```

its supposed to save succesfuly

Comment: Can you extrapolate a little bit more on what information you have and what exactly you're trying to save?

Comment: What error are you currently seeing? Are you sure you can append to 'outfile'? As far as I am aware, your variable 'outfile' is not a list so you would need to use '.write(' rather than '.append('

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for i in range(0, len(card_list)):
    outfile.write(str(card_list[i]) + '\n')
```

or

```
for card in card_list:
    outfile.write(str(card) + '\n')
```

and don't forget to do `outfile.close()` The file is buffered in memory (if your changes are small) prior to this. If you are trying to append to the file if it exists, use `"a"` instead of `"w"`

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to solve your issue.

Your original loop:

```
for i in card_list:
    outfile.append(str(card_list[i]) + "\n")
```

should probably become

```
for card in card_list:
    outfile.append(str(card) + "\n")
```

(or some other variable name). Since you are not using the index, usually denoted by 'i', there is no reason to explicitly get the index out.

There are ways to do so though:

`for i, card in enumerate(card_list):`
would make `str(card)` and `str(card_list[i])` completely equal.

Enumerate allows you to get each item from your list (e.g. 'card') and the index of the item in the list (e.g. 'i')

You could also use `range` if you wanted the index of the item in the list:
`for i in range(len(card_list) - 1):`

Range creates a list of numbers so this call asks for a list containing numbers from 0 to the number of items in card_list. If card_list contains 2 items, e.g. ['card1', 'card2'], that is index 0 and index 1. So if you don't subtract 1 when creating the range list: e.g. `range(len(card_list))` you would get a list of `[0, 1, 2]` and when the loop hits the '2', the index would be out of range for `card_list[i]`.

I'm also concerned that there is no 'append' method for writing to a file, but I am not knowledgeable around the methods for a file. I believe you need to use `.write(` rather than `.append(` when writing to a file. What makes it append versus overwrite a file is around the way you open the file in the first place.